Не удается качать аудио с ютуб(видео)
Установил: pytubefix
yt = pytubefix('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+code, on_progress_callback = on_progress)
yt.streams.get_highest_resolution(progressive = False).download(output_path = pt)
yt.streams.get_audio_only().download(mp3=True, output_path = pt)

python3.12 /dw.py
File "/dw.py", line 32, in loading
yt.streams.get_audio_only().download(mp3=True, output_path = pt)
TypeError: Stream.download() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mp3'

Все хорошо, видео скачивает, а вот аудио к сожалению нет.
Не понимаю в чем тут дело, но другом сервере все работает...
В чем тут дело?

[python] !!!!!!

Stream.download() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mp3' сообщение об ошибке вам прямо говорит - в функции download не поддерживается параметр mp3. Уберите его из вызова.
